# segmentation fault when returning string from function

Tags: c

I was wondering what this code should print. I wanted to check whether it prints `we can, can we` or `we can`, but instead i got segmentation fault.

Here is the code:

```
char* mysubstr() {
    char* x = "Yes we can, can we";
    char* y = "we can";
    char* tmp = x;
    
    while(*tmp) {
        if (*tmp == *y)
            return *tmp;
        tmp++;
    }
    return x;
}


void main() {
    printf("%s", mysubstr());
}
```

I think the wrong part is the `return *tmp;`, but why? What's wrong with that?

Comment: What has your compiler to say to this line `return *tmp;` ? What type is `tmp` and what is `*tmp`?

Comment: Your function name indicates you want to implement some substring searching. But your function will return as soon as the first character of `y` is found and returns a `'w'` then

Comment: i get a warning that says ```return makes pointer from integer without a cast```. Does it means the compiler thinks this ```*tmp``` is an integer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

Comment: @JHBonarius that dupe is about returning address of local nonstatic buffer. No relation to this question.

Comment: @ryden the compiler does not only think it is an integer. It **is** an integer. Actually a `char` to be more precise.

Comment: @JHBonarius that is again a dupe about local buffers. Please read this question before suggesting similar wrong dupes.

Comment: The root problem is this [What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565) Ensure that you get compiler errors when writing invalid C, so you don't waste time troubleshooting bugs that the compiler has already found for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following works:

```
char* mysubstr()
   {
       char* x = "Yes we can, can we";
       char* y = "we can";
       char* tmp = x;
  
       while(*tmp)
       {
           if(*tmp == *y)
           {
               return (char*) tmp;
           }
           tmp++;
       }
       return (char*) x;
   }
  
   int main()
   {
       printf("%s", mysubstr());
       return 0;
  }
```

And the answer is:

```
**We can, can we**
```

Answer (score 1):

Your compiler basically already told you what is wrong:

```
return makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

This is because you define a function returning a `char *` but you return a `char`.

With `char *tmp = x;` you define a pointer and in your return statement you dereference it.
Hence you return `(char*)'w'`

If you use that return value for `printf` value `'w'` is taken an address which causes your crash.

You should just do `return tmp;`

This is not the only issue in your code.
Your function name indicates you want to make some substring function.
Bur your code returns immediately it found a match of first letter in second string. You don't verify if the other character also are same.

Comment: @ryden be aware that the warning "return makes pointer from integer without a cast" is almost always an error.